# Implementation of Random Forest using alglib in C++

Tags: c++, random-forest

I am a novice in C++, who is trying to implemenent Random Forest Algorithm by Leo Breimen.
I have worked with Random Forest algorithm in MATLAB with the code for 
 https://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/ and I am able to train and test with an accuracy of 98%
for my Phd thesis, now I need to work with RF using C++. I am trying to use alglib

```
g++ dataanalysis.cpp -o  analyzer
```

I tried compiling the dataanalysis.cpp, resulted me with the following error.

http://pastebin.com/bxmRa4pq

Any suggestions of using other multi class Random Forest algorithm (Original algorithm by Breimen)

Comment: You might need to link additional file(s).

Comment: Yup, go to your linker settings on your ide or check g++ for how to link external libraries. You must first compile your library into an *.a or *.so file, you also need the include files. This might seem like too much but its basic library linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check gcc for the path where libalglib.a is installed, for example:

```
gcc -lalglib -L/my/path/
```

Check include files, you are adding none or some?

```
gcc -I/my/path/alglib/include
```

complete it would look like this

```
gcc -I/my/path/alglib/include -lalglib -L/my/path/
```